# How to serve specific static files with nginx?

Tags: nginx, static-files

I have queries like `/api/lang?lang=en` which I want to serve with nginx as `/server/i18n-angular/en.json`. How can I do that?

I have the following directory structure:

```
/public/
/server/i18n-angular/en.json
```

I have the following configuration, but nginx says it is wrong to use index directive at that point.

```
server {
  root /public
  ...
  location /api/lang {
    if ($args ~* "\?lang=(.+)") {
      set $language $1;
      index ../server/i18n-angular/$language.json;
    }
  }
}
```

What directive should I use instead of `index`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see that you need a separate `location` at all. A simple `rewrite` should do.

For instance:

```
server {
    rewrite /api/lang /server/i18n-angular/$arg_lang.json last;
```

Comment: Thx Michael for the answer. It turns out a simple /../server suffices for rewrite. I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: what does `last` mean?